# How do I stop a list overflowing its webpart and overwriting the webparts below it?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I am using SharePoint 2010. I created three linked lists and they worked fine. Especially the first list, as it displayed all the records with a scroll bar. This allowed the user to search all the records in the list, not just the ones visible in the webpart.

I then attempted to replicate this setup but this time the first two lists were created by exporting data from an MS Access 2013 query to SharePoint lists. This time the records in the first two lists are not contained within their webparts. The contents of these lists overflow the webparts and literally overwrite the webparts below them.

I have set **Should the Web Part have a fixed height?** to 200 pixels.
When viewing the source code in Internet Explorer the overflowing lists have `style="height:200px;"`. The list that doesn't overflow has `style=height:200px;overvlow:auto;"`.

However when viewing the code for the page in SharePoint Designer I cannot find either of these style items.

What do I need to edit or add in SharePoint Designer to get these two lists to behave?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a CSS issue; it has (maybe inherited) `overflow:visible;` somewhere, use F12 Developer Tools to check what the *computed* CSS for overflow is (on all related elements in the DOM chain)

You need to apply `overflow:hidden;` (on one of the parent DOM elements could be enough)